# Should I have a cart table in my e-commerce app, or just have an open order status?

Tags: database-design, schema, e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart

I'm working on an e-commerce app, and while designing the database schema, I stumbled on two questions about storing cart data.

First, is there any reason to have both a cart and a cart_line table? 
I get why this is done with things like orders. It obviously prevents duplicate data across multiple order lines (the order number, order date, user/account, status, etc.) by substituting it instead for a single foreign key of orderID.

But the only data like this that would be shared across cart lines (that I foresee) would be the user.
So instead of storing a reference to a cartID in the cart line, why not just store the userID and eliminate the cart table entirely?

Am I overlooking another benefit of having a dedicated cart table?

And then secondly, pondering that question made me wonder if I even need a cart line table.
If orders have a status, why not just have an 'open' status and use open orders for user carts?

I realize that this would mean searching the (larger) order_lines table instead of the cart_lines table to retrieve the user's cart. I'm just wondering how much of a difference that would actually make. And if it's perhaps normal practice to use the orders table to store cart data.

Any feedback or discussion would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason for doing this is to allow one user to have "more than one cart."  Sometimes a user does need to "park" an unfinished order and place another one before returning to the unfinished order to complete or discard it.

So, there's a one-to-many relationship between users and carts, *and* a one-to-many relationship between a cart and the items that it contains.

Now ... I also strongly suggest that you spend time looking at *existing* e-commerce frameworks in the language of your choice.  Don't unnecessarily reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the input!
That's definitely a valid argument against my first question. A cart line table on its own would not suffice. 

But would this not be achievable using the order status approach? 

Part of what sparked these thoughts was wanting to give users the ability to save an order for later, and store the entire order.
I thought this could be easily implemented by having a 'saved' order status. This way users could have multiple saved orders as they would be identified by order number. But the cart page/drawer would be populated with the "open" orders order lines.